# Join three tables together to find which table rows are missing from

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables which contain an id column. I would like to join these three tables together to produce a single table which has the ids and their corresponding matches.
E.g.
table A:

| id_A |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 4 |

table B:

| id_B |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

table C:

| id_C |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

Would produce:

| id_A | id_B | id_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 4 |  | 4 |
|  | 3 | 3 |

I currently am using a full outer join:

```
SELECT * FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON id_A = id_B
FULL OUTER JOIN C ON id_A = id_C
```

But this means that table C would not join on anything in that is not in table A but is in table B, e.g. we end up with:

| id_A | id_B | id_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 4 |  | 4 |
|  | 3 |  |
|  |  | 3 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-can-i-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4qvPu7Db3TmB7pgVTk2ZBP/1 as a live example to tinker with. Emulating a FULL OUTER JOIN with 2 tables is straightforward, but adding the third table will take some more experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

A UNION of these three queries works for your example:

```
select A.id_A, B.id_B, C.id_C
from A
left join B
  on A.id_A = B.id_B
left join C
  on A.id_A = C.id_C
union
select A.id_A, B.id_B, C.id_C
from B
left join A
  on B.id_B = A.id_A
left join C
  on B.id_B = C.id_C
union
select A.id_A, B.id_B, C.id_C
from C
left join A 
  on C.id_C = A.id_A
left join B
  on C.id_C = B.id_B
```

Output:

| id_A | id_B | id_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 4 |  | 4 |
|  | 3 | 3 |
|  |  | 5 |

---

Comment: There should be one more union for case there is 5 in C table only...

Comment: @Betlista Good catch, I updated the query and output if there was an id of "5" found only in table C.